# Use srcset to load small preview of big image first

Tags: html, css, angular, srcset, angular17

Is there a clean way of laoding a small preview for a big image first to reduce the time where the website is white only?
Can the `srcset` property in general or more specifically the [NgOptimizedImage](https://angular.io/guide/image-directive#responsive-images) Angular directive be leveraged to solve that?
I read many proposals for plain HTML about using a background image but this seems to have the problem that the whole resolution is loaded before the preview is loaded in at least some cases.

Currently my code is:

```html
<img width="6000" height="3200" alt=""
     ngSrc="assets/avatar" ngSrcset="600w, 1000w, 1500w, 2000w, 2500w, 3000w, 6000w"
/>
```

Comment: It depends on the use case what the best solution is. To avoid additional requests, I'd like to stick to whatever I already have loaded. Often it will just be a simple svg and/or background color to be replaced when the full image is loaded.
Another strategy could be interlacing the image.
If you still want previews - a 100px blur is probably enough.
(Sorry for not exactly answering your question. "clean way" might be a personal preference I have no answer to)

Comment: @René thank u very much for the reference, interlacing was exactly what I was searching for!